# Access to the elements of Array of Jsons

Tags: java

I have seen many examples, but none of them are not like what i want.

Consider I have a `JSONObject` like:

```
[ {
  "id" : "572add95e4b0b04f4d502a3c",
  "amount" : 109.27,
  "sourceCurrency" : "MXN",
  "targetCurrency" : "USD",
  "recipientBankId" : "572add95e4b0b04f4d502a37",
  "iban" : "5805742027",
  "created" : "2016-05-05T05:43:49.194"
}, {
  "id" : "572add95e4b0b04f4d502a3e",
  "amount" : 722.41,
  "sourceCurrency" : "GBP",
  "targetCurrency" : "INR",
  "recipientBankId" : "572add95e4b0b04f4d502a32",
  "iban" : "4688276585",
  "created" : "2016-05-05T05:43:49.2"
}]
```

and i want to access to the second json and `iban` value.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

With your json content

```
String json = "[ {\n" +
                "  \"id\" : \"572add95e4b0b04f4d502a3c\",\n" +
                "  \"amount\" : 109.27,\n" +
                "  \"sourceCurrency\" : \"MXN\",\n" +
                "  \"targetCurrency\" : \"USD\",\n" +
                "  \"recipientBankId\" : \"572add95e4b0b04f4d502a37\",\n" +
                "  \"iban\" : \"5805742027\",\n" +
                "  \"created\" : \"2016-05-05T05:43:49.194\"\n" +
                "}, {\n" +
                "  \"id\" : \"572add95e4b0b04f4d502a3e\",\n" +
                "  \"amount\" : 722.41,\n" +
                "  \"sourceCurrency\" : \"GBP\",\n" +
                "  \"targetCurrency\" : \"INR\",\n" +
                "  \"recipientBankId\" : \"572add95e4b0b04f4d502a32\",\n" +
                "  \"iban\" : \"4688276585\",\n" +
                "  \"created\" : \"2016-05-05T05:43:49.2\"\n" +
                "}]";
```

You first need to get a JSONArray from your json content :

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
```

Then you read the second ( at the index 1 ) JSONObject within the array:

```
JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(1);
```

And finally you read the iban from the JSONObject :

```
String secondIban = o.getString("iban");
System.out.println(secondIban);
```

With of course all this surrounded with a try/catch to catch `JSONException`:

```
try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
    JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(1);
    String secondIban = o.getString("iban");
    System.out.println(secondIban);
}catch(JSONException jse){
    jse.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Note**

If you want to be aware that the iban field doesn't exist use `o.getString("iban")`.
A JSONException will be thrown if the field is missing.

If you are okay to work with an empty string `""` as default value for the eventually missing field then use `o.optString("iban")` to read the field.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "[{\n" +
            "  \"id\" : \"572add95e4b0b04f4d502a3c\",\n" +
            "  \"amount\" : 109.27,\n" +
            "  \"sourceCurrency\" : \"MXN\",\n" +
            "  \"targetCurrency\" : \"USD\",\n" +
            "  \"recipientBankId\" : \"572add95e4b0b04f4d502a37\",\n" +
            "  \"iban\" : \"5805742027\",\n" +
            "  \"created\" : \"2016-05-05T05:43:49.194\"\n" +
            "}, {\n" +
            "  \"id\" : \"572add95e4b0b04f4d502a3e\",\n" +
            "  \"amount\" : 722.41,\n" +
            "  \"sourceCurrency\" : \"GBP\",\n" +
            "  \"targetCurrency\" : \"INR\",\n" +
            "  \"recipientBankId\" : \"572add95e4b0b04f4d502a32\",\n" +
            "  \"iban\" : \"4688276585\",\n" +
            "  \"created\" : \"2016-05-05T05:43:49.2\"\n" +
            "}]";
    JSONArray objects = new JSONArray(json);
    System.out.println(((JSONObject)objects.get(1)).get("iban"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `optString` instead `getString`.

`optString` - Will return blank string if element/key not found in JSON.

`getString` - Will throw an exception.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
================================
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    String str = "[{\"id\":\"572add95e4b0b04f4d502a3c\",\"amount\":109.27,\"sourceCurrency\":\"MXN\",\"targetCurrency\":\"USD\",\"recipientBankId\":\"572add95e4b0b04f4d502a37\",\"iban\":\"5805742027\",\"created\":\"2016-05-05T05:43:49.194\"},{\"id\":\"572add95e4b0b04f4d502a3e\",\"amount\":722.41,\"sourceCurrency\":\"GBP\",\"targetCurrency\":\"INR\",\"recipientBankId\":\"572add95e4b0b04f4d502a32\",\"iban\":\"4688276585\",\"created\":\"2016-05-05T05:43:49.2\"}]";
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
        /* optString - will return blank string if element not found */
        String iban = jsonObject.optString("iban");
        System.out.println(iban);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is transform string into json:

```
public JsonObject parseJsonString(String jsonString) {
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonString);
    return jsonObject;
}
```

then extract values that you are after:

```
final String iban = jsonObject.get("iban").getAsString();
```

Answer (score 0):

To read a value from JSON you can only with the next methods:

1. Data bind
2. Tree Model
3. Streaming API
4. XPath like

Which method to use is up to you because all methods have advantage and disadvantage.

Engines:

- [Fastjson](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson) supports **Data bind, XPath like**
- [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) supports **Data bind, Tree Model, Streaming API**
- [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) supports **Data bind, Tree Model, Streaming API**
- [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) supports **XPath like**
- [Genson](http://owlike.github.io/genson/) supports **Data bind, Tree model with Jsonp, Streaming API**
- [Ig json parser](https://github.com/Instagram/ig-json-parser) supports **Data bind**
- [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) supports **Data bind**
- [JSON java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) supports **Tree Model**
- [LoganSquare](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare) supports **Data bind**

I guess you want to select only a part from json, so xpath like could be your choice with syntax like this `$[1].iban` (JsonPath)